# RDP connection from mobaxterm in linux

Tags: ubuntu-22.04

I have Mobaxterm professional 23.X install on Ubuntu via wine.
connection to ssh is ok but i can't connect to windows server via RDP connection (I can connect via Remmina). Connection going out after 4-5 second.
I don't have a firewall issue since i logon to windows server via Remmina.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried regarding this? What do log show? We need more information before we can begin to understand this question enough to begin providing answers. Please add the information I have asked for and any other relevant information to the post itself, using the EDIT button. Do not add information in comments down here. Ask questions in the comments, but do not add information down here.